# How do we set setMetadata in azure fileclient for Azure Data Lake in C#

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am getting while setting meta data in azure data lake file using azure fileclient, it's throwing the *exception like "Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters. Parameter name: name in azure data lake"*

I am using the Dictionary to set metadata.

```
PathHttpHeaders path = new PathHttpHeaders();
path.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
fileClient.SetHttpHeaders(path);
var metaDataProperties = await GetMetaDataProperties(entityData);
await fileClient.SetMetadataAsync(metaDataProperties);
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: var entityData = JObject.Parse(wrapper.Payload);
var metaDataProperties = await GetMetaDataProperties(entityData);
await fileClient.SetMetadataAsync(metaDataProperties);

Comment: COuld you please tell me which service you use? Gen1 or Gen2?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample data?

Comment: GEN 2, now it's working, the same fileclient instance was not setting the metadata which I have used to store the file into datalake.
To resolve the issue I have created a new fileclient instance and it worked for me.

Comment: @gouravbhattacharya Since the issue has been resolved by yourself, could you please post your solution?

Comment: Hi @JimXu I have added my code which worked for me. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue has been resolved, the issue was coming due to the FileClient instance, I was using the same FileClient instance which I have used to store the file into the Azure data lake. For resolving the issue I have created a new FileClient Instance and that worked for me. Below is my code.

```
private async Task SetMetaDataProps(MessageWrapper wrapper, Uri uri, string filename)
        {
            
            try
            {
                var entityData = JObject.Parse(wrapper.Payload);
                entityData["FileName"] = filename;
                var storageCredentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("accountName", "accountKey");
                var fileclient = new DataLakeFileClient(uri, storageCredentials);
                var metaDataProps = await GetMetaDataProperties(entityData);
                var ss = fileclient.SetMetadataAsync(metaDataProps);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```